# Is there a good way or a plugin that can easily go to the end of a function of python in vim

Tags: python, vim

When I look at python code, I find it is hard to find out where is the end of a function if it has too much lines of code.

I first think about just to find next `def` will be ok. But if the function is a decorator like below, this method doesn't work.

```
def require_player(view_func):
    @warps(view_func)
    def decorate(request, *args, **kwds):
        #my code here
        return
    return decorate
```

So my want to know is is there any good way to do this in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[python-mode](https://github.com/klen/python-mode) has keybindings for this: e.g. `[[` and `]]` will jump back and forth between top-level functions.  In your case, it would ignore the inner `def`, which I think is what you're asking.

It's a lot of Kool-Aid to drink, but so far I haven't seen any serious overhead when not using its features.  So I leave it installed and go see what else it can do when I feel like it—kinda like I do with vim.

Comment: `[[` and `]]` are actually defined in the default python ftplugin.

Comment: HA, so they are.  well then.

Answer (score 0):

There are Vim scripts/plugins that are designed to handle exactly these kinds of cases for you, such as [Python.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=30) - they'll give you bindings that you can use to easily skip to/select functions, classes, et cetera.